# ParseFile does not save to ParseUser (Android)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I must be missing something with the way I am saving ParseFile to the Parse DB. I am simple trying to pick a picture from my gallery, crop it and than save it to the Parse DB to be used later as a profile picture.

**Any ideas why the image is not being saved?**

```
public class UserActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

Context context;
private ParseImageView ivProfilePic;
private TextView tvUserName, tvBio, tvTagLine;

private static final String TAG = "OwlSample";
private static final int RESULT_OK = 0;

final int PHOTO_WIDTH = 300;
final int PHOTO_HEIGHT = 300;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist. The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed. Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    LinearLayout mLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_user_fragment, container, false);

    Button logoutButton = (Button) mLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.log_out_button);
    logoutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button editProfileButton = (Button) mLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.btn_editProfile);
    editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageButton btnFindFriends = (ImageButton) mLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.btn_friends);
    btnFindFriends.setOnClickListener(this);

    tvUserName = (TextView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_name);
    tvBio = (TextView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_bio);
    tvTagLine = (TextView) mLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_tagline);
    ivProfilePic = (ParseImageView) mLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.imageViewUserProfile);

    ivProfilePic.setOnClickListener(this);

    updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
    return mLayout;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        // Check if the user is currently logged
        // and show any cached content
        updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
    } else {
        // If the user is not logged in, go to the
        // activity showing the login view.
        showLoginActivity();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.log_out_button:
        Log.e(TAG, "Tapped sign out");
        onLogoutButtonClicked();
        break;

    case R.id.btn_editProfile:
        Log.e(TAG, "Tapped editProfile button");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditProfileActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    case R.id.btn_friends:
        Log.e(TAG, "Tapped editProfile button");

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(),
                FriendSearchActivity.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent1);
        break;

    case R.id.imageViewUserProfile:

        Intent intent2 = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        intent2.setType("image/*");
        intent2.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent2.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent2.putExtra("outputX", PHOTO_WIDTH);
        intent2.putExtra("outputY", PHOTO_HEIGHT);
        intent2.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent2.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent2.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);

    }

}

private void showLoginActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void onLogoutButtonClicked() {
    // Log the user out
    ParseUser.logOut();

    // Go to the login view
    showLoginActivity();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {

            final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

            Bitmap bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] data1 = stream.toByteArray();

            final ParseFile profilePicture = new ParseFile("profilePicture",
                    data1);
            profilePicture.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                  public void done(ParseException e) {
                    currentUser.put("photo", profilePicture);
                    currentUser.saveInBackground();
                    updateViewsWithProfileInfo(); 
                  }
                });

        }
    }
}

private void updateViewsWithProfileInfo() {
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser.getString("displayName") != null) {
        tvUserName.setText(currentUser.getString("displayName"));
    } else {
        tvUserName.setText("");
    }

    if (currentUser.getString("bio") != null) {
        tvBio.setText(currentUser.getString("bio"));
    } else {
        tvBio.setText("");
    }

    if (currentUser.getString("tagline") != null) {
        tvTagLine.setText(currentUser.getString("tagline"));
    } else {
        tvTagLine.setText("");
    }

    ParseFile imageFile = currentUser.getParseFile("photo");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        ivProfilePic.setParseFile(imageFile);
        ivProfilePic.loadInBackground();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it is because the ParseFil is not saved before you assign it to the PFUser.

in your code:

```
profilePicture.saveInBackground();         // this takes a long time but returns immediately
currentUser.put("photo", profilePicture);
currentUser.saveInBackground();
updateViewsWithProfileInfo();              // executes without PFFile really existing
```

You want to adopt the version of saveInBackground that uses a callback:

```
profilePicture.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    currentUser.put("photo", profilePicture);
    currentUser.saveInBackground();
    updateViewsWithProfileInfo(); 
  }
});
```

Or something like that but it working code.

Comment: I updated the code, but it still doesn't seem to save properly. It is odd because I have another portion of code that save an imagefile perfectly and in the exact same way.

Perhaps there is a problem when the picture is cropped/saved?

Comment: What does the data look like in your console? Can you see the link to a PFFile? Have you checked the PFFile object locally - log its URL and see if you can open that in a browser.

Comment: In Parse I do not see any existence of the ParseFile having been created. I tried to do a test to see if the Bitmap was being returned properly after the image was cropped/saved by setting it to the ImageView, but it does not change the ImageView at all. How would I log its URL?